# (Angular) Set *ngFor " i " value as (data.id)

Tags: angular, ngfor

When using the *ngFor, i want to store in the ' let i = ... ' a value different than 'index', because i'll be using it as the ID of the elements of the list.

This is basically what i want:

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of User; let i = {{data.id}}"></div>
```

I have tried like this, as well like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of User; let i = (data.id)"></div>
```

or:

```
 <div *ngFor="let data of User; data.id as i"></div>
```

My last try was using trackBy. But it failed miserably

Nothing works, the app stops. Is this even possible? How can, I do it?

EDIT

So, i've been asked to provide more detais.

I'm using this ngFor for display some info from my db. But it need each element to have an ID. That ID MUST be the same as in the db. If i just use 'i = index', the ID will be from (0 - last), but i dont want that. I need the ID to be what in my db, whch is why, ' i = index' is not viable, i need somethoing like 'i = data.id'

Comment: i dont know if you read my question, but it's very different from stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute/35405648#35405648

Comment: In my case, i want to put the data thats being displayed AS the value of " i "

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `i` for this, rather than just doing `[id]="data.id"` or something?

Comment: Not really, how would be the sintax for that? Because *ngFor="let data of User; [id]='data.codigo015'" does not work (sorry, i never used this)

Comment: I need to IDs to send an array with all the IDs to my API,

Comment: Hey  @JohnMontgomery, your idea worked. Please, post it as an answer, so i can accept it

Comment: @CH4B You have to put it outside of the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to go to all that trouble, because you can already bind the id to the value directly. e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let data of User" [id]="data.id"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the following

```
'$implicit.id' as i
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8agswk